# Media queries not working in responsive web design with grids

Tags: html, css, grid

CSS used on the page to display grid elements in different viewport size
Code to display the grid and its descendants based on size of the viewport . If the size of the screen becomes smaller then based on the size of screen the columns should drop and acquire a single row in mobile mode for each container.
In case of tablet mode main and sidebar should drop from 2nd row to third row.

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.gridContainer{
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;

    grid-template-columns: 20% 1em 1fr 1em 20% ;
        grid-template-rows:  4.4em 1em 1fr 1em 4.4em;
    grid-template-areas: "header header header header header"
        ". . . . ."
        "navigation . mainContent . sidebar"
        ". . . . ."
        "footer footer footer footer footer";
}
.gridHeader{
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: #A62E5C;
}

.gridFooter{
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color: #A62E5C;
}

.gridNav{
    grid-area: navigation;
    background-color: #9BC850;
}

.gridMain{
    grid-area: mainContent;
    background-color: #9BC850;
}

.gridSide{
    grid-area:  sidebar;
    background-color: #9BC850;
}

.grid-item {
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    .grid-container {
        grid: 1fr 1em 30% / 4.4em 1em 3.6em 1em 1fr 1em 4.4em;
        grid-template-areas:
        "header header header"
        ". . ."
        "navigation navigation navigation"
        ". . ."
        "content . sidebar"
        ". . ."
        "footer footer footer";
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .gridContainer{
        grid: 1fr / 3.6em 1em 4.6em 1em 1fr 1em 4.6em 1em 3.6em;
        grid-template-areas: "header"
            "."
            "navigation"
            "."
            "mainContent"
            "."
            "sidebar"
            "."
            "footer";
    }    
}
```

HTML used on the page to display grid elements in different viewport size

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <title>
            Modern Web Layout
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main class="gridContainer">
        <header class="gridHeader grid-item">
            HEADER
        </header>
            <section class="gridNav grid-item">
                NAVIGATION AREA
            </section>
            <section class="gridMain grid-item">
                MAIN CONTENT
            </section>
            <section class="gridSide grid-item">
                SIDEBAR
            </section>
            <footer class="gridFooter grid-item">
                FOOTER
            </footer>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help.....Thanks in advance

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zEjOEa)

Comment: What have you tried so far that isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used .grid-container instead of .gridContainer for tablet layout.

Comment: I did the change still it is not changing based on layout , it seems to be some browser support issue(using grid-template-columns and grid-template-rows in place of grid to layout grid worked for me).

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this problem yesterday, and it was very simple instead of just `@media screen` its `@media only screen` Hopefully that works for you!

Comment: Sorry about that.